# What is ajax error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, client-server

What server response cause ajaxError on browser Ajax handler?
Is this error code different from 200 or not empty special json field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, non-200 response codes *can* cause an error, [you can see what constitutes "success" here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L636-645):

```
httpSuccess: function( xhr ) {
    try {
        // IE error sometimes returns 1223 when it should be 204 so treat it as success, see #1450
        return !xhr.status && location.protocol === "file:" ||
            xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300 ||
            xhr.status === 304 || xhr.status === 1223;
    } catch(e) {}

    return false;
}
```

This is as of jQuery 1.4.4, previous a status code of `0` was also successful, because Opera `304` was reported as a `0`...that leniency has since been removed to eliminate false positives for success.  If the above check is `false`, [the error handler is called](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L436-443).